# How to use a function when the current time equals another time: Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am developing a script that utilizes a function I made to control the relays of an 8 channel relay board on a Raspberry Pi 3. The function works, and calling the function works. I am trying to develop this script so when the current time equals another time, such as Zone 1 start time, the relays turn on/off depending on the status that is received by another part in the code.

I have tested it without this time equals part, and everything works. I seem to be running into some problems when I add this level of complexity. Here is a sample of my code:

```
while True: 
  from datetime import datetime
  import time
  import smbus    

  ValveStatus='00000001' #0 is closed, 1 is open.
  R1_1,R2_1,R3_1,R4_1,R5_1,R6_1,R7_1,R8_1=list(map(int, ValveStatus))


  currenttime=datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  Z1S_Timestamp='2018-07-09 10:25:11'


 if(currenttime==Z1S_Timestamp):
    if(R8_1==1):
        SetRelayState(BoardOne,8,"ON")
    else:
        SetRelayState(BoardOne,8,"OFF")
```

No matter how many times I changed the code, it will never work with this timing method. It never enters the loop and therefore the relay never opens. Is there a better way to do this rather than simply having if equal to statements? I am open to editing it, but the relays still need to open around the time of the start time. I think a margin of 1 or 2 minutes is okay, since timing it exactly equal is not 100% necessary.

Would something like:

```
currenttime= '2018-07-09 12:53:55' #hard coding just for example purposes

if('2018-07-09 12:52:55' <= currenttime <= '2018-07-09 12:54:55'):
     do the things
```

Be a more valid/correct/pythonically correct method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure - I would do the opposite though - convert all times to `datetime()` objects and use those for comparison:

```
TIME_MARGIN = datetime.timedelta(seconds=120) # use a margin of 2 minutes

time_compare = datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 9, 12, 52, 55)

current_time = datetime.datetime.now()

if (time_compare - TIME_MARGIN) < current_time < (time_compare + TIME_MARGIN):
     #do something
```

Comment: This is the sort of thing I was looking to do, but unfortunately had no where to start or how to write it. This is really awesome, thank you so much! I'll make some edits and see how it goes. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I've edited and it works perfectly. You have no idea how much you've helped! Thank you again!

Comment: @SwankyTigers you could also get how many seconds you have to wait by using `time_to_wait = (time_compare - current_time).total_seconds()` and then wait that exact time `time.sleep(time_to_wait)`. That way you don't have to repeteadly check.

Comment: Hm okay, I'll test out my current edits and then expand on the code.